# Showing ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use the following matrices and perform a dot product as shown in the code. I checked the size of the matrix and it is (1, 3) but it is throwing me error for the dot product.

```py
import numpy as np 

b0 = np.matrix(np.random.rand(3))
n1 = np.cross(b0, b0)
print(np.shape(n1))

y = np.dot(n1, n1)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By converting the matrix to array by using

```
n12 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(n2))

X12 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x1))
```

solved the issue.

Comment: silly question - where does your solution fit in original code?

Answer (score 8):

The column of the first matrix and the row of the second matrix should be equal and the order should be like this only

```
column of first matrix = row of second matrix
```

and do not follow the below step

```
row of first matrix  = column of second matrix
```

it will throw an error

Answer (score 5):

Unlike standard arithmetic, which desires matching dimensions, dot products require that the dimensions are one of:

- `(X..., A, B) dot (Y..., B, C) -> (X..., Y..., A, C)`, where `...` means "0 or more different values
- `(B,) dot (B, C) -> (C,)`
- `(A, B) dot (B,) -> (A,)`
- `(B,) dot (B,) -> ()`

Your problem is that you are using `np.matrix`, which is totally unnecessary in your code - the main purpose of `np.matrix` is to translate `a * b` into `np.dot(a, b)`. As a general rule, `np.matrix` is probably not a good choice.

Answer (score 5):

```
numpy.dot(a, b, out=None)
```

Dot product of two arrays.

For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last of `b`.

Documentation: [numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Input the transpose of n2 into dot product:

`np.dot(x1, n2.T)`

For a dot product to work, the dimensions of the input matrices must meet a certain criteria: the size of the column of the first matrix = the size of the row of the second matrix.

You have both matrices with dimensions (1,3):
`x1.shape => (1,3), n2.shape => (1,3)`.
Following the above rule, you need `x1.shape => (1,3), n2.shape => (3,1)`.
This is easily accomplished by taking the transpose of n2, shown above.

Answer (score 1):

This error may also show up when using `statsmodels`. The endogenous variable is the first positional argument in `statsmodels.api.OLS`, so messing up the order shows this error. For example,

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = [[1,2,3]]*100
y = [1,2]*50
model = sm.OLS(x, y).fit()     # <---- ValueError
model.summary()

# ValueError: shapes (100,3) and (100,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 100 (dim 0)
```

Passing the arguments in the correct order resolves the error:

```py
model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()     # <---- OK
#              ^^^^       <---- change the order of `y` and `x`
model.summary()
```