# Python: Newton, Hessian, Jacobian Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, newtons-method, hessian

Hi I am trying to use newton method to minimise a function but I keep getting this error when I run the code and I don't know why. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Error:

```
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Code:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import symbols
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la
from scipy.optimize import minimize
a1=0.3
a2=0.6
a3=0.2
b1=5
b2=26
b3=3
c1=40
c2=1
c3=10
h=0.000001

def TutFunc(x):
    x=np.empty((2,1))
    u = x[0][0] - 0.8
    v = x[1][0] - ((a1+(a2*u**2))*(1-u)**0.5-(a3*u))
    alpha = -b1+b2*u**2*(1-u)**0.5+b3*u
    beta = c1*v**2*(1-c2*v)/(1+c3*u**2)
    y= alpha*np.exp(-beta)
    return y

def JacobianFun(x):
    x=np.empty((2,1))
    Jx1 = (TutFunc(x+[[h],[0]]) - TutFunc(x-[[h],[0]]))/(2*h)
    Jx2 = (TutFunc(x+[[0],[h]]) - TutFunc(x-[[0],[h]]))/(2*h)
    jaco = np.array([[Jx1],[Jx2]])
    return jaco

def HessianFun(x): 
    x=np.empty((2,1))
    Hx1x1 = (TutFunc(x+[[h],[0]]) - 2*TutFunc(x) + TutFunc(x-[[h],[0]]))/h**2
    Hx1x2 = (TutFunc(x+[[h],[h]]) - TutFunc(x+[[h],[-h]]) - TutFunc(x+[[-h],[h]]) + TutFunc(x-[[h],[h]]))/(4*h**2)
    Hx2x1 = Hx1x2
    Hx2x2 = (TutFunc(x+[[0],[h]]) - 2*TutFunc(x) + TutFunc(x-[[0],[h]]))/h**2
    Hess = np.array([[Hx1x1, Hx1x2],[ Hx2x1, Hx2x2]])
    return Hess

x0=([0.7, 0.3]
x=minimize(TutFunc,x0,method= 'Newton-CG', jac=JacobianFun, hess=HessianFun)
```

Comment: what is meant by `x0=([0.7, 0.3]`? it is incomplete expression

Comment: I think it should be x0 = np.array ([0.7 ,0.3])

Comment: @Syed Noor Ali Jafri - that possibly solves it! More clues for OP at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608421/showing-valueerror-shapes-1-3-and-1-3-not-aligned-3-dim-1-1-dim-0

Comment: x0 = np.array ([0.7 ,0.3]) gives 2,0 dimension and x0= np.array ([[0.7], [0.3]]) gives dimension 2,1 . OP can check the dimension using x0.shape. This might give you the clue for dimensional error.

Comment: @SyedNoorAliJafri that doesn't solve it, the same error occurs

Comment: looking deeper in code - you repeat ```def JacobianFun(x):  x=np.empty((2,1))``` that effectively wipes our an argument in every function, I think this is wrong behaviour.

Comment: @EPo  he then uses it initialising it. I don't know whatever it is but the error is generating somewhere else.

Comment: @Syed Noor Ali Jafri - no point in passing x to a fucntion then overwritying it. I think OP has to specify what he is after: retruning a matrix of functions or calculting a value ot some point `x`, I think the code becomes a mixture of the two ways and it is unclear what type `JacobianFun` is returning - a vector of floats of a vector of two fucntions.

Comment: Upon debugging minimise function uses numpy.dot(ri, ri) which brings us closer to error. CHeck this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028991/numpy-dot-dimensions-not-aligned

Comment: @Nu2prog are you sure you have jacobian function right? Please check my solution, optimisation achieved though :p

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to optimised your output. You need to alter your jacobian and hessian function. I have altered the jacobian, hessian you need to do yourself.

[See the documentation here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

According to the documentation: jac(x) -> array_like, shape (n,)
Which means jacobian function takes **x** which is an ndarray and returns **array** with (n,0) dimension. In your case (2,0). You on the other hand had (2,2) so I switched between both of them one by one to achieve optimisation. You can go through the documentation if you like. Second thing is hess and hessp are two different functions.

**hess** : hess(x, *args) -> {LinearOperator, spmatrix, array}, (n, n)

takes arguments and return something I really have no idea about. Whereas by seeing your code I think you were thinking of using:

**hessp**: hessp(x, p, *args) ->  ndarray shape (n,)

Which takes arguments and return ndarray of shape(n,)

For simplicity I have disabled **hessp**

Plus I don't see a point why were you initialising the array **X** by an empty one.

Here is the code:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import symbols
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la
from scipy.optimize import minimize
a1=0.3
a2=0.6
a3=0.2
b1=5
b2=26
b3=3
c1=40
c2=1
c3=10
h=0.000001
flag = 0

def TutFunc(x):
    u = x[0] - 0.8
    v = x[1] - ((a1+(a2*u**2))*(1-u)**0.5-(a3*u))
    alpha = -b1+b2*u**2*(1-u)**0.5+b3*u
    beta = c1*v**2*(1-c2*v)/(1+c3*u**2)
    y= alpha*np.exp(-beta)
    return y

def JacobianFun(x):
    global flag
    Jx1 = (TutFunc(x+[[h],[0]]) - TutFunc(x-[[h],[0]]))/(2*h)
    Jx2 = (TutFunc(x+[[0],[h]]) - TutFunc(x-[[0],[h]]))/(2*h)
    jaco = np.array([Jx1 , Jx2])
    if flag == 0:
        flag = 1
        return jaco[0]
    else:
        flag = 0
        return jaco[1]

def HessianFun(x): 
    x=x
    Hx1x1 = (TutFunc(x+[[h],[0]]) - 2*TutFunc(x) + TutFunc(x-[[h],[0]]))/h**2
    Hx1x2 = (TutFunc(x+[[h],[h]]) - TutFunc(x+[[h],[-h]]) - TutFunc(x+[[-h],[h]]) + TutFunc(x-[[h],[h]]))/(4*h**2)
    Hx2x1 = Hx1x2
    Hx2x2 = (TutFunc(x+[[0],[h]]) - 2*TutFunc(x) + TutFunc(x-[[0],[h]]))/h**2
    Hess = np.array([[Hx1x1, Hx1x2],[ Hx2x1, Hx2x2]])
    if flag == 0:
        flag = 1
        return Hess[0]
    else:
        flag = 0
        return Hess[1]


x0= np.array([0.7, 0.3])
x0.shape
x=minimize(TutFunc,x0,method= 'Newton-CG', jac=JacobianFun, hessp=None)
print(x)
```

OUTPUT for **x** when hess function is dissabled

```
    jac: array([ 2.64884244, -2.89355671])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
   nfev: 2
   nhev: 0
    nit: 1
   njev: 6
 status: 0
success: True
      x: array([0.69999996, 0.30000004])
```

Comment: @Nu2prog did you try the solution?